# Aggregating Across Datetimes

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I am parsing a file that has one column with a datetime (actually a string in a csv file) in this format (12/9/2015 6:11) and an integer value in the second column.

The datetime values span a few weeks but do not include every minute of every day.

I would like to do the following:
-for every minute in the file, calculate the sum of column 2 values from any values that include that minute plus the next 5 minutes. Below is a sample input and a sample desired output:

**Input**

```
Col1, Col2

12/9/2015 6:12, 5
12/9/2015 6:13, 10
12/9/2015 6:13, 15
12/9/2015 6:14, 10
12/9/2015 6:27, 5
```

**Desired Output**

```
12/9/2015 6:12, 40
12/9/2015 6:13, 35
12/9/2015 6:14, 10
12/9/2015 6:27, 5
```

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Please, always follow up on people's answers to your questions, and vote accordingly. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

input = '''12/9/2015 6:12, 5
12/9/2015 6:13, 10
12/9/2015 6:13, 15
12/9/2015 6:14, 10
12/9/2015 6:27, 5'''

parsed = defaultdict(int)

for line in input.splitlines():
    date_str, v = line.split(',')
    parsed[datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')] += int(v)

final = {}
for dt, v in parsed.items():
    candidates_dt = [dt + timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(6)]
    final[dt] = sum(parsed[candidate_dt]
                    for candidate_dt
                    in candidates_dt
                    if candidate_dt in parsed)

print parsed
{
    datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 6, 27): 5,
    datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 6, 14): 10,
    datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 6, 13): 35,
    datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 9, 6, 12): 40
}
```

Voila! :)

**Explanation**:

1. You have / might have multiple lines with the same date in your file

   -> I use `defaultdict(int)` to create a **unique key per date** and **be able to add every values found for that date** while reading the file
2. Then, for each of the **dates/sum of values** read from the file, I generate the **next 5 minutes for that date** and **sum up the values of each of the following dates if found in the initial parsed data** from the file